# Installing QGIS using software distribution?

Tags: qgis, installation

In our company we use QGIS 3.4.8 (LTR). To install the same version for each user in a short time we use the rollout software, Baramundi.

It works for the most installations, but for one installation we get this error message:

> The job [QGIS 3.4.8 INST] was completed with error: the installation
>   of [QGIS Development Team QGIS 3.4.8] failed: the execution of
>   baramundi deploy scripts failed: the returned returncode [#2] is not
>   valid (step: extern proces
>   [C:_baradir\depot\Q-GIS_3_4_8_LTR\source\QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.4.8-1-Setup-x86_64.exe
>   /S] start, row 41)

Does anyone know this error and know what we have to do?

Comment: See that you are missing a \ in `C: _baradir` .I don't know what Baramundi is, but that path is not correct

Comment: If it is for only one computer, what about installing it manually for this special computer ?

Comment: I suggest not to distribute QGIS via software distribution. A better way is to install QGIS once on an application server using OSGeo4W installer and then distribute a link to \\your_application_server\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis-ltr-bin.exe